# Reading command line parameters inside quotes in a shell function

Tags: shell

I want to create a function in `zshrc` for the following command -

`node scripts/node_es6.js scripts/small_run_oneoff.js runMiaEventsStatsJob '{"targetDate": "02-01-2018"}'`

I want to pass the `targetDate` as a command line argument. So, I wrote the following function in `zshrc` -

```
function mia-events-stats() {
    node scripts/node_es6.js scripts/small_run_oneoff.js runMiaEventsStatsJob '{"targetDate": "$1"}'
}
```

This however does not work. When I execute `mia-events-stats 02-01-2018`, the `targetDate` passed to the actual running code is `$1`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is not particular to *zsh* and *oh-my-zsh*. Neither it is to functions. It is the case for any script in any shell interpreter. Maybe you could change your tags. Also, the title of your post is very general and do not sum up your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters of a string inside single quotes is quoted. Thus, your dollar sign is read as a normal character.

You should replace your single quotes by doubles quotes to let the magic happen, and escape inner double quotes like that:

```
"{\"targetDate\": \"$1\"}"
```

If you need your single quotes to be read, simply add them:

```
"'{\"targetDate\": \"$1\"}'"
```

Single quotes won't have any effect thanks to doubles quotes.